# Error '>' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python

Hasta ahora el único error que me manda es el de:

```
if years>=18: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
```

El erro lo manca en la función llamada: `titular_valido`.

Pero no entiendo por que el error, ya que estoy declarando a `years` como un `int`, también me ayudaría mucho si me hicieran alguna observación sobre el código, espero me puedan ayudar, la verdad soy principiante.

El ejercicio trata sobre la creación de un programa que presente un filtro que compruebe que el usuario tenga entre los 18 y los 25 años, si cumple con esto se le da una bonificación del 10% sobre su cantidad en su cuenta, después le pregunta al usuario si desea hacer un retiro un deposito

```
 class cuenta_joven:
    def __init__(self,titular,edad,cantidad):
        self.titular=titular
        self.edad=edad
        self.cantidad=cantidad

    def datos(self, titular, edad, cantidad):
        print("Estos son sus datos...")
        print("Nombre del titular: ",dueño.titular)
        print("Edad del titular: ",dueño.edad)
        print("Dinero en cuenta: ",dueño.cantidad)
        

    def titular_valido(self, years, porcentaje, total, money):
        if years<=18 and years>=25:
            print("Usted es Titular Valido")
            print("tiene una bonificacion del 10%")
            porcentaje=money*bon
            total=money + porcentaje
            print("saldo final es : ",total)
        else:
            print("Usted no es titular valido")
        return

    def retirar(cuenta_joven,ret):

        ret=float(input("cuanto desea retirar?: "))
        if ret<0:
            print("operacion fallida")

        else:
            print("solicitud exitosa")
            print(money - ret,"es el saldo final")

    def deposito(cuenta_joven,dep):

        dep=float(input("cuanto desea depositar"))

        if dep<0:
            print("operacion fallida")

        else:
            print("solicitud exitosa")
            print(money + dep,"es el saldo final")


    def menu(deposito,retirar):

        print('''Que operacion desea realizar?:
        1 retiro
        2 deposito''')

        opcion=int(input())

        if opcion==1:
                print("Escogio retiro")
                dueño.retirar(money)

        elif opcion==2:
            print("Escogio deposito")
            dueño.deposito(money)

bon=.10
nom=str(input("Titular de la cuenta: "))
years=int(input("Ingrese su edad: "))
money=float(input("Ingrese su saldo actual: "))
dueño=cuenta_joven(nom, years, money)
total=0
porcentaje=0


dueño.datos(nom, years, money)
dueño.titular_valido(cuenta_joven,years,money,total)
dueño.menu(cuenta_joven)
```

Comment: El primer parámetro que reciben todos los métodos de instancia por convención es `self` que hace referencia a la propia clase, este parámetro es el único que no debe ser pasado en la llamada al método, pues python lo pasa internamente. En tu llamada a `dueño.titular_valido(cuenta_joven,years,money,total)`  le estas pasando la clase explícitamente y es esta la que se toma como el argumento `year`  dentro de tu método, de ahí el error. Solo quita ese "argumento". pues `self` ya se lo pasa python cuando llamas al método.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema está en como utilizas el método `titular_valido`

1. `self` hace referencia a la instancia actual de la clase y no hay que pasarlo como argumento
2. Hace falta el argumento `porcentaje`
3. No porque crees variables con los mismos nombres que los argumentos el método va a adivinar qué variable corresponde a cual argumento

Es decir, tu método recibe los siguientes argumentos

```
def titular_valido(self, years, porcentaje, total, money):
```

Como mencioné, `self` no se pasa como argumento, pero `years`, `porcentaje`, `total` y `money` son argumentos obligatorios (Ya que no los declaraste como opcionales)

Para utilizar el método tienes dos opciones

1. Indicarle al método la variable que se va a relacionar a cada argumento

```
dueño.titular_valido(years=years,money=money,total=total,porcentaje=porcentaje)
```

2. Pasar los argumentos en el mismo orden que fueron declarados

```
dueño.titular_valido(years, porcentaje, total, money)
```

Esta última forma es lo que ocaciona tu error, tu estás intentando

```
dueño.titular_valido(cuenta_joven,years,money,total)
```

Dentro del método lo que sucede es que los argumentos se asignan de la siguiente forma:

```
years = cuenta_joven
porcentaje = years
total = money
money = total
```

Ya que si no se indica el nombre del argumento siempre se asignan en el orden que fueron declarados (Recuerda `self` no se recibe como argumento, es únicamente para indicarle al método que pertenece a la instancia actual de la clase)

**Nota adicional:** Es recomendable que los nombres de las variables utilicen únicamente letras que pertenecen al abecedario en inglés (Es decir, evitar la `ñ`). Referencia: [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a tomar en cuenta todo lo que me idicates

Answer (score 0):

### ¡Buen dia!

Al momento de llamar al metodo *titular_valido* le esta pasando nuevamente la clase ***cuenta_joven*** solo tiene que quitar ese argumento y pasarle los paramentros que recibe su meotodo *titulo_valido* que para este caso serian *"years, porcentaje, total, money"* dicho esto su intancia quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
dueño.titular_valido(years, porcentaje,total, money)
```

### Nota adicional:

Analizando detalladamente su código en cada método recibe y pasa como parámetro su clase *(cuenta_joven)* siendo esto un error; usted deberiá eliminar en cada uno de sus metodos ese parametro y reemplazarlo por
*`self`*

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu comentario me sirvio mucho

Comment: Un gusto haberte ayudado!